# QGIS - moving dataset

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a point data set that is recorded close to Ottawa in Canada. I am going to use it in some training and for the training purposes, I would like to move the data set to a place a bit east of Cape Town in South Africa, i.e I want to move the data approximately 90 degrees eastwards and 80 degrees southwards.

Is there any way to do this in QGIS (I don't mind running a Python script in the console) or do I have to write a Python script to parse the file I initially imported into QGIS?

The data are presently used in QGIS as WGS84 UTM 18N, but I have no problem reprojecting it to WGS84 lat/lon if that makes things easier.

(I know moving the dataset to another latitude will change the shape of it, it may be that I need to be a bit more careful with the CRSs like - moving it to the southern hemisphere in the same UTM zone, then move it eastwards by manipulating UTM zones and adjusting the easting values, but for a first attempt I am pretty sure lat=lat-80, lon=lon+90 would be good enough for what I need it for)

Comment: There's so many ways to do this, it's not clear why you haven't tried one. If it's a one-off process for one dataset, you could  just clobber the spatial reference and drag&drop. Pick something that makes sense to you, try it, and if you have trouble, then update the question with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Vector geometry -> **Translate** tool. You can set the offset for the X- and Y-axis.

Comment: Thanks, I only was looking into the Vector menu, I forget the processing all the time.